# C# synchronising received datas via serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

Please have a look at my code below, which is a part of application which purpose is drawing an online chart  based on datas received via serial port. And that part of code is responsible for reciving and drawing:

```
   private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,  SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

                rx_str = serialPort1.ReadTo("\r\n");
                //rx_str = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();

            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(rx_parse));      
    }

     private void rx_parse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Match mch = Regex.Match(rx_str, ex_reg);
            data.Add(Convert.ToInt16(mch.Value.ToString());
       chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(Convert.ToDouble(data[tab_size]));

        tab_size++;

    }
```

used variables has created earlier:

rx_str - string

data - List of doubles

tab_size - int

ex_reg - used pattern of regular expression

In this case I have real problem with synchronising received datas from the buffer.
To testing it, I measure something via ADC in mirocontroller and send it as string to PC.

Lets take such example - received datas can look like this: 373\r\n

I'm using regular expression to taking only digits from received string. Very often datas get to the string rx_str from the buffer,  for that example, as: 73\r\n3, 3, \n37, \n3 etc instead of 373\r\n in every cycle. So, then I processing datas that are in wrong order and it causes wrong results in chart.

Please give me an advise how can I synchronise it to receive the same order of signs in every time when I get datas from buffer. I mean to get the same form of received datas.
 I add that I 've checked it via terminal and everything is ok, in every time was the same form of datas. For this example - 373\r\n

Comment: The Invoke() call can cause a great deal of delay.  Very troublesome in general since it is so likely to cause deadlock on the Close() call.  But necessary here to avoid the threading-race bug on rx_str.  That makes DiscardInBuffer() quite lethal, it throws data away you haven't read yet.  Exactly what is lost is unpredictable.  It must be deleted from the code.  The delay caused by Invoke() may still cause additional data loss due to overrun errors, be sure to also implement the ErrorReceived event so you can see that happening.

Comment: And note that this *guaranteed* to go wrong, you never remove any data from the chart.  This will make it slower and slower.  Once the UI can no longer keep up with the data rate, and the serial port handshaking isn't reliable enough, then the receive buffer will overflow.  Also generally noticeable from losing all control over the UI.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you Discard the data in the in buffer.
The in buffer could contain 373\r\n37
You read to \r\n and that leaves 37 in the buffer. You then discard the in buffer with the line

```
serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
```

this removes 37 and the next time you read you get 3\r\n

Remove that line and it should be predictable.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting

serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();

isn't fully enough solution. And also calling Invoke is needed because chart has been created in the other thread.

I solved this problem by organising the transmition in this way:

I created completely seperated thread, which only reads transmition. It just doesn't base on the event serialPort1_DataReceived. And then:

1.I send to microcontroller any char to allow transmition

2.Microcontroller send to PC measurment along with char at the end

3. In C# I give: 
    serialport1.ReadTo("char at the end of frame")

And at the end I call delegate to use chart.

This whole solution is being repeated constantly in the loop and gives control of buffer content.

Thank you for your help